# how to provide a extra target argument to input_fn of tf.estimator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

As you know, in order to utilize tf.estimator, one needs to implement the model function builds a pipeline that yields batches of (features, labels) pairs, therefore the signature should be as following:

```
model_fn(features, labels, mode, params, config):
```

These features and labels should be returned from the input_fn. We assume that features -> X, and labels-> y, I am having a problem here because I have two type of labels.(targets, labels)

```
Features = X : [None, 2048]
Labels = targets: [None, 2048]
         labels: [None, 1]
```

In order to provide targets and labels as separate arguments instead of just one label argument, what would be the alternative?

Note: I tried to concatenate targets and labels, then slice them where it needs but it created an additional problem during execution of the model. Therefore I am wondering whether you guys have any other better ideas or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `input_fn`, you can simply return a dictionary instead of a tensor as labels. That is, your input function likely returns an iterator over a tuple `(features, labels)`. Both `features` and `labels` can either be a single tensor or a `dict`. This dict should map from strings to tensors.

You can prepare the dataset as one returning three elements `(features, targets, labels)`, and then include a mapping to pack the targets into a dict (there might be better ways but this works):

```
data = ...  # prepare dataset of 3-tuples

def pack_in_dict(features, targets, labels):
    return features, {"targets": targets, "labels": labels}

data = data.map(pack_in_dict)
```

Now, if one of the elements is a dict (say, `labels`), then the corresponding input to `model_fn` will also be a dict. You can then simply use `labels["targets"]` and `labels["labels"]` in your `model_fn`.

Comment: Thank you @xdurch0, let me try on it and update here if anything happens exceptionally.